# Median/Percentiles for "histogram-style data"

Tags: google-sheets

I have data in the following format:

```
actions | users
1       | 321000
2       | 104520
```

The first row represents 321,000 users taking 1 action, and the next row represents 104,520 users taking 2 actions.

How can I calculate the median and percentiles for this data? Even better if there is a way to convert this data to something where I can easily use all the normal functions to calculate the mean, cdf, etc.

Comment: can you add how you imagine your desired output to look like?

Comment: Sure, scroll down to "Grouped Data" on this page to get an idea of what I mean: https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/frequency-grouped-mean-median-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

```
=MEDIAN(B2:B3)
```




```
=AVERAGE(B2:B3)
```




```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), NORMSDIST(B2:B),))
```




```
=FREQUENCY(B2:B3, A2:A3)
```

[image: 0]